# How to use TEXTSPLIT on a column from a dynamic array spill range in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dynamic array of data with a column that contains a duration as text that I will convert into a numerical time value. I use TEXPSPLIT to split the duration as text value into days, hours, mins, secs then convert each numerically. TEXTSPLIT works when the duration as text is a column in a table but not when it is a column in a dynamic array.

With a " " delimiter, TEXTSPLIT on the dynamic array column outputs the first array element only, whereas TEXTSPLIT on static text outputs the complete array, as expected.

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A2#," ")
```

[image]

I've tried using this inside a LET, with CHOOSECOLS, with a LAMBDA, and no success. For whatever reason, the function seems to see the input but treat it differently when within a spill range.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y," ")))),""),1)
```

---

• Or, Formula used in cell `B8`

```
=LET(x,A8:A11,
IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(" "&x," ",
SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(x))))&" "," "),SEQUENCE(,8,1)),""))
```

---

**Note:** In the second formula I have used `SEQUENCE(,8,1)` deliberately to take 8 columns for each rows otherwise it was spilling for 14/15 columns.

---

### Edit : 8/27/2023

Update with and without <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> with a different approach where in using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTAFTER( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2#,
     b,LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a," ",))+1,
     c,SEQUENCE(,MAX(b)),
     IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" "&a&" "," ",c)," "),""))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell B2 with <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2#,
     b,LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a," ",))+1,
     c,SEQUENCE(,MAX(b)),
     DROP(REDUCE("",c,LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,IFERROR(
     TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" "&a&" "," ",y)," "),"")))),,1))
```

---

Applied a similar approach in this question: **[reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76985094/8162520)**

Answer (score 7):

Use TEXTJOIN to introduce a character to denote a row split and then TEXTSPLIT:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",,A2#)," ","|",TRUE),"")
```

[image]

One note, TEXTJOIN does have a limit of 32,767 characters and as such, if the dataset is too large this approach may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the TEXTJOIN character limit, I feel your pain. I wrote up a little workaround (kind of dumbed-down version of TEXTSPLIT and TEXTJOIN) in VBA for a job I am working on. Data is well-formed, so I don't have to worry about "ignoring blanks" - that would require much more logic in this code that I did not need. However, it works just fine for my purposes. I suppose it might help here.

You call "BigTextJoinThenSplit" with a cell formula something like this:

=BigTextJoinThenSplit(AL4:AL40,";","$")

Where the first parameter is a range of cells to split, second parameter is column delimiter, and third parameter is row delimiter.

```
Option Explicit

Function BigTextJoinThenSplit(ByVal inputArray As Range, ByVal colDelimiter As String, ByVal rowDelimiter As String) As Variant
    
    Dim bigString As String
    bigString = BigTextJoin(rowDelimiter, inputArray)

    Dim resultArray As Variant
    resultArray = BigTextSplit(bigString, colDelimiter, rowDelimiter)

    BigTextJoinThenSplit = resultArray

End Function


Function BigTextJoin(ByVal delimiter As String, ByVal inputArray As Range) As String

    Dim result As String
    result = ""
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = inputArray.rows.Count
    
    For r = 1 To rowCount
        result = result + inputArray.Cells(r, 1)
        If r < rowCount Then
            result = result + delimiter
        End If
    Next r
    
    BigTextJoin = result

End Function



Function BigTextSplit(ByVal text As Variant, ByVal colDelimiter As String, ByVal rowDelimiter As String) As Variant
    
    Dim resultArray As Variant
    
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    rowCount = Len(text) - Len(Replace(text, rowDelimiter, "")) + 1
    
    Dim colCount As Integer
    colCount = 1 + (Len(text) - Len(Replace(text, colDelimiter, "")) + 1) / rowCount
    
    ReDim resultArray(1 To rowCount, 1 To colCount)
    
    Dim rows() As String
    rows = Split(text, rowDelimiter)
    
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer
    
    For iRow = 1 To rowCount
        
        Dim row As String
        row = rows(iRow - 1)
        
        Dim cols() As String
        cols = Split(row, colDelimiter)
        
        For iCol = 1 To colCount
            
            resultArray(iRow, iCol) = cols(iCol - 1)
            
        Next iCol
    
    Next iRow
    
    
    BigTextSplit = resultArray

End Function
```

Comment: You wrote this code to get around the TEXTJOIN character limit, but that's not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ, it kinda is a response to the OP, since one of the simplest answers would be TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(... but that runs into problems with long arrays and the TEXTJOIN character limit.

Answer (score 0):

Works if the greatest number of delimiters occurs in the first cell.

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(TestArray2),1+LEN(INDEX(TestArray2,1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(TestArray2,1),"#","")),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c=1,TEXTBEFORE(INDEX(TestArray2,r),"#",1,0,0),TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(INDEX(TestArray2,1),"#",c-1,1,1),"#",1,0,1))))
```

MAKEARRAY is used to build output counting delimiters for columns. TEXTBEFORE and TEXTAFTER are used to parse.

Notes on a partial solution below from before I found the general solution above, kept for reference

This is only a partial solution, but one that worked for me in a similar situation. Cautions: 1. This only works for splitting 1 delimited column into 2, although I think it could be extended by someone with more time or knowledge to the n-column case.  Caution 2: I'm using Index to extract values from the input array; I'm sure there are better ways.
The heart of this approach is simply to use MAKEARRAY and apply TEXTBEFORE to the first column and TEXTAFTER to the second.

Example
Input Array is a single column: `[{"A Foo : 3","B Bar : 6","C Kilroy : 9","D Jack : 12"}  ]` [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSida.png)
Output Array is two columns: `[{("A Foo",3),("B Bar",6),("C Kilroy",9),("D Jack",12)}]`[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwlkY.png)

Single Formula is:
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:A5),2,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c=1,TEXTBEFORE(INDEX(A2:A5,r,1)," : ",1,0,0),TEXTAFTER(INDEX(A2:A5,r,1)," : ",1,0,0))))

Explanation:
 `=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:A5),2,`     ; we want an array as long as our input, two columns wide.
`LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c=1,`     ; we test for the first column
 `TEXTBEFORE(INDEX(A2:A5,r,1)," : ",1,0,0),`    ; TEXTBEFORE handles the parse for column 1.
  `TEXTAFTER(INDEX(A2:A5,r,1)," : ",1,0,0))))`   ; TEXTAFTER handles the parse for the remaining.

Note:
After further testing: this seems to work in the general case:

`=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(TestArray2),3,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c=1,TEXTBEFORE(INDEX(TestArray2,r),"#",1,0,0),TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(INDEX(TestArray2,1),"#",c-1,1,1),"#",1,0,1))))`