# Return split values in a dynamic range and include blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created a formula that addresses the limitation that `TEXTSPLIT` has at not being able to spill a set of split values by a delimiter.

Here it is:

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(" ", A2:A11, LAMBDA(x,y, IF(ISBLANK(y), x, VSTACK(x, TEXTSPLIT(y, " "))))), ""), 1)
```

[image]

The problem is that blank values are skipped, and I want to find a way to include them. How do I do this? Preferably, it would be nice to have the option to switch this on or off if I'm using it as a custom `LAMBDA` function.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do this without any <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function aka without <kbd>REDUCE( )</kbd>. Using only <kbd>TEXTAFTER( )</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd>.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A11,
     b,LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a," ",))+1,
     c,SEQUENCE(,MAX(b)),
     IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" "&a&" "," ",c)," "),""))
```

---

Using <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper <kbd>REDUCE( )</kbd>, it will be

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A11,
     b,LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a," ",))+1,
     c,SEQUENCE(,MAX(b)),
     DROP(REDUCE("",c,LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,IFERROR(
     TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" "&a&" "," ",y)," "),"")))),,1))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, undoubtedly:

```
=MAKEARRAY(
    ROWS(A2:A8),
    MAX(LEN(A2:A8) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A8, " ", "")) + 1),
    LAMBDA(row, col,
        IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A2:A8, row), " "), col), "")
    )
)
```

[image]